# A language model with only one embedding layer in both encode and decode only predict <eos>

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I'm trying to make the model predict a word from a sentence using pretrained Huggingface's BERT as feature extractor. The model look like this

```
class BertAutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size):
        super().__init__()
        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(768, 2, 1024, dropout=0.1)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, 2)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(768, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, memory, embedded_word):
        output = self.transformer_decoder(embedded_word, memory)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output
```

And when train/evaluate I call the model like this

```
bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
bert.requires_grad_(False)
...
memory = bert(**src).last_hidden_state.transpose(0, 1)
embeded_word = bert.embeddings(trg.data['input_ids'][:, :-1], token_type_ids=trg.data['token_type_ids'][:, :-1]).transpose(0, 1)
output = model(memory, embeded_word)
```

The loss reduced nicely but turned out the model only predict `<eos>` token.

I tried train the model with 1 batch of 32 samples and it did work when loss reduced pass `8e-6` but when I trained it with all data the loss could go way beyond that but none of the saved models work. Even the one with eval or train loss around `4e-6` - `8e-6`.

Surprisingly the model would work if I use a separate decoder's Embedding like this

```
class BertAutoEncoderOld(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size):
        super().__init__()
        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(768, 2, 1024, dropout=0.1)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, 2)
        self.decoder = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, 768)
        self.pos_decoder = PositionalEncoding(768, 0.5)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(768, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, memory, word):
        tgt = self.decoder(word.data['input_ids'][:, :-1].transpose(0, 1))
        tgt = self.pos_decoder(tgt)
        output = self.transformer_decoder(tgt, memory)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output
```

But I was asked to make it work with one Embedding and I have no idea how.

I tried

- Reduce/increase batch from 32 to 8-64
- Also tried 2 and 1024 batch size
- Remove `<eos>` token and change it's attention mask to 0

But none of those work.

What did I do wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

## Edit per @emily qeustion

I change the data itself in collate function

```
text.data['attention_mask'][text.data['input_ids'] == 102] = 0
text.data['input_ids'][text.data['input_ids'] == 102] = 0
word.data['attention_mask'][word.data['input_ids'] == 102] = 0
word.data['input_ids'][word.data['input_ids'] == 102] = 0
```

It only used in Bert though.

Comment: You mentioned attention mask, but I didnt see any variable in your code that is a mask?

Comment: @emily I added that part